# Which frontend framework for consuming resources described with json schema?

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js, ember.js, angularjs, jsonschema

Given that I have an API which describes it's different resources via json-schema like this:
https://github.com/salesking/sk_api_schema/blob/master/json/v1.0/address.json

Is there a frontend javascript framework that can use json-schema as (or translate it to) a model? it should be possible to validate the model against the json schema and it should be able to handle references between different json-schema models.

I have been looking a bit at ember.js but it seems that even if i write some code to translate the json schema to an ember model, it would still be a far cry to get the validation working for ember.js models. Correct?

Comment: also, the resources are not static, so handrolling models is not possible

Comment: I don't think any of the listed frameworks can do this out-of-the-box. With knockout specifically, you would also the the additional difficulty of creating a view (UI) from your indeterminable object graph after you managed to construct it.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about JSON Schema, I believe Knockout can support this fairly easily.

Since KO models can be any Javascript object, you would just need read the schema, and generate an object from each of the "properties" property's properties (haha)

You can also add validation dynamically using the Knockout Validation plugin:
https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Combined example:

```
var schema = // read in json
var model = {}

for (prop in schema.properties) {
    model[prop] = ko.observable().extend({ 
                      maxLength: /* get your value from schema, etc */,
                      minLength: /* get your value from schema, etc */
                  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JXT (http://www.jxtdev.com) models are initialized with JSON, moreover JSON is used to configure JavaScript packages. JXT implements the MVC pattern and when data contained in the model changes, it will notify its controller which will reload the view automatically. This event driven approach is used everywhere in the framework, starting from JXT collections (which are wrappers around native JavaScript collection). I just released the first beta (yes, I'm the developer behind it), so you may find it still immature, but it worth a look imo ;)